# Check AVX instruction set support

Tags: c#, windows

In C#, how to check if current CPU and OS support [AVX instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)?

I need to choose which native DLL to load, SSE2 or AVX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best way is to pinvoke [GetEnabledXStateFeatures()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh134235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it ensures that both the processor and the OS support AVX:

```
public static bool HasAvxSupport() {
    try {
        return (GetEnabledXStateFeatures() & 4) != 0;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern long GetEnabledXStateFeatures();
```

No decent way to distinguish between AVX and AVX2 btw, luckily you didn't ask for that.