# import tensorflow error in windows server 2016 (DLL load failed importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, windows-server-2016

I want to run my tensorflow python program in Windows servre 2016 *(X 5650 x64 processor , Dell Power Edge 710)*
The same environment works on local pc but showing error in server device.

**ERROR :**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py",
>   line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py",
>   line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import tensorflow   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 50, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 69, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py",
>   line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py",
>   line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Im trying to solve this for 2 days and nothing came out.

**Notes  :**

> -i have set http_proxy for pip
>
> -i have tried installing vc_redist.x64.exe and vc_redist.x86.exe
>
> -i put msvcp140_1.dll in python folder.

Please Help !

Answer (score 2):

After some more research i found that..
**Intel X 5650 x64 processor** does not support **AVX instruction** which is necessary for tensor-flow.
So, it this happens one has to check if his/her CPU support AVX instructions or not.

In most of older CPUs doesn't support this AVX instruction set.

Comment: @mattsmith5 instead of using server device i'm using latest 4 pc cluster