# Tensorflow model inference in .NET on x86 platform

Tags: c#, tensorflow, machine-learning, x86, microsoft.ml

I have a trained TensorFlow model that is correctly saved as a [pb model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794378/correct-pb-file-to-move-tensorflow-model-into-ml-net) to load into .NET and perform inference.  The .NET program will build correctly if the target is a 64 bit (x64), but when the platform target is changed to 32 bit (x86), it will throw an exception:

[image]

If you google the exception a top result is a [stack overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549580/unable-to-load-dll-tensorflow-or-one-of-its-dependencies-ml-net) from 2019 where the second answer says:

> **Reason 1:** Microsoft.ML works on **x64 only**

which does not look promising.  However, earlier that year there was an article in [devblogs.microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/what-is-ml-net-1-0-machine-learning-for-net/) where a little more detail is given on the supported architecture:

> - x64 bit is supported on all platforms.
> - x86 is supported on Windows, except for TensorFlow, LightGBM, and ONNX related functionality.

Another article in [devblogs.microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ml-net-1-4-global-availability-machine-learning-for-net/) by the same author later in the year says:

> ML.NET uses C++ code that is hard-coded to x86-based SSE instructions.

This sounds more promising since TensorFlow easily transfers into C++.

Since all of these were written almost 3 years ago, and there was support for x86 just not yet for Tensorflow and it is built using C++ per the third article, has anything changed at all?  I tried looking through the Microsoft.ML and didn't find anything.  I also haven't found a more recent article on the discussion.  Is there a different way that I can save the TensorFlow model to make it work on x86 in .NET?  Is the support for TensorFlow in C# on x86 now available?  What are possible workarounds?

Comment: With File Explorer check BIN folder of project.  When should have to folder 1) x64 2) Debug (for x64) applications.  I think you are missing the DEbug folder and need to build project as x64.?

Comment: @jdweng I'm not interested in x64 - I can build just fine in 64 bit.  I want to build in x86 - 32 bit.  I do have the Debug folder inside of bin.

Comment: The debug folder needs a dll (in the subfolders) and the project must be looking for the x86 dll in the correct subfolder.

Comment: @jdweng You're right.  The win-x64 folder has a tensorflow.dll file in it and the win-x86 folder does not.  I'm not finding a tensorflow.dll for 32 bit readily available online - everything suggests building it yourself.

Comment: Search for following : github tensorflow x86