# DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Azure-AI-Vision-Core' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, vision

[image]

I had this error after I deployed the Azure Service application (web application).

I reinstalled the Azure.AI.Vision.Core from Nuget, but it didn't fix it.

Has anyone experienced this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The dll file must be missing from the ...bin/Debug directory. Have you tried locating it in the reference manager and making sure it is checked?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (an "unable to load DLL 'Azure-AI-Vision-Native'" error when deployed to an Azure app service). [This response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58793359/19036) to a similar problem pointed me in the right direction...namely, changing my app service to 64 bit under "Configuration" >> "General settings" in the Azure portal:

[image]

Apparently, the Azure AI libraries are 64 bit-only.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key issue is not just `x64` only. It because the Azure AI Vision SDK have need some [Prerequisites](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-ai-vision-sdk/blob/main/samples/csharp/image-analysis/dotnet/README-Windows.md).

- A Windows 10 (or higher) **x64** PC. We only support **x64** platforms at the moment.
- [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist) for your platform.
- [.NET Runtime 6.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0) or later installed. ( I tested in [.NET Runtime 8.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/8.0), it works. )

You also need to deploy required libraries for run-time distribution. The output folder contains many DLL files needed to support different sets of Vision SDK APIs. For **Image Analysis**, only the following subset is needed when you distribute a run-time package of your application:

```
Azure.AI.Vision.Common.dll
Azure.AI.Vision.ImageAnalysis.dll
runtimes\win-x64\native\Azure-AI-Vision-Native.dll
runtimes\win-x64\native\Azure-AI-Vision-Extension-Image.dll
runtimes\win-x64\native\Azure-AI-Vision-Input-Device.dll
```